# Python Argparse: Issue with optional arguments which are negative numbers

Tags: python, argparse, negative-number

I'm having a small issue with `argparse`. I have an option `xlim` which is the `xrange` of a plot. I want to be able to pass numbers like `-2e-5`. However this does not work - `argparse` interprets this is a positional argument. If I do `-0.00002` it works: `argparse` reads it as a negative number. Is it possible to have able to read in `-2e-3`?

The code is below, and an example of how I would run it is:

```
./blaa.py --xlim -2.e-3 1e4
```

If I do the following it works:

```
./blaa.py --xlim -0.002 1e4
```

The code:

```
parser.add_argument('--xlim', nargs = 2,
                  help = 'X axis limits',
                  action = 'store', type = float, 
                  default = [-1.e-3, 1.e-3])
```

Whilst I can get it to work this way I would really rather be able to use scientific notation. Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/p/argparse/issues/detail?id=37 it should have been fixed. Check whether the version of argparse you have is newer or same.

Comment: @nmichaels  
Hi, do you mean like "-2e-5"? It doesn't work unfortunately, I think it still interprets it as an argument. The exact error from 

    `./blah.py -xlim "-.2e-5" 1e5`

is --xlim: expected 2 argument(s). If I use \- it thinks its a string and then complains because it should be a float

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't appear to have been fixed. However, it only affects options which have more than one argument and can be negative. Irritating workaround is to use `--xlower` and `--xupper` with the quoted notation: `--xlower="-1.e-3"`. That works

Comment: @favoretti
Hi - I just tried v1.2 and it still an issue.

Comment: @Chris
Hi, thanks for the input. I think I am going to look at parsing the sys.argv before I give it to argparse.

Comment: So I can't answer my question because I don't have enough reputation. I am going to put it here in case I forget to come back and do it: This is the solution I've come up with. I parse sys.argv, check if xlim is found, then edit the next two entries. I turn them into floats and then back into strings. Quite crude but it works :)
    `for i in sys.argv[1:]:
       if i == '--xlim':
           sys.argv[sys.argv.index(i) + 1] = str(float(sys.argv[sys.argv.index(i) + 1 ]))

    args = parser.parse_args()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As already pointed out by the comments, the problem is that a `-` prefix is parsed as an option instead of as an argument. One way to workaround this is change the prefix used for options with [`prefix_chars`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('@@xlim', nargs = 2,
                  help = 'X axis limits',
                  action = 'store', type = float,
                  default = [-1.e-3, 1.e-3])
print parser.parse_args()
```

Example output:

```
$ ./blaa.py @@xlim -2.e-3 1e4
Namespace(xlim=[-0.002, 10000.0])
```

Edit: Alternatively, you can keep using `-` as separator, pass `xlim` as a single value  and use a function in `type`  to implement your own parsing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

def two_floats(value):
    values = value.split()
    if len(values) != 2:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError
    values = map(float, values)
    return values

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--xlim', 
                  help = 'X axis limits',
                  action = 'store', type=two_floats,
                  default = [-1.e-3, 1.e-3])
print parser.parse_args()
```

Example output:

```
$ ./blaa.py --xlim "-2e-3 1e4"
Namespace(xlim=[-0.002, 10000.0])
```

Comment: I really wanted to keep the `-` as the separator so I did a crude parsing of sys.argv before I called parse_args(). The way I did it is in a comment above, but your way is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

One workaround I've found is to quote the value, but adding a space. That is,

```
./blaa.py --xlim " -2.e-3" 1e4
```

This way argparse won't think -2.e-3 is an option name because the first character is not a hyphen-dash, but it will still be converted properly to a float because float(string) ignores spaces on the left.

Comment: nice! Worked for me in a completely different language / environment also

Comment: I made a little preprocessor that scans sys.argv for "xlim" and adds a space to the beginning (via your answer). I put this before the call to argparse, and it seems to be working well...
`for indx in range(len(sys.argv) - 1):
    if 'xlim' in sys.argv[indx]:
        sys.argv[indx + 1] = ' {0}'.format(sys.argv[indx + 1])`

Comment: Clever. However, if your type is `str` (the default) and not `float`, your option value will have an extra space to strip out. A [more general workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060857/1727828) is to use an equals sign: `--xlim=-2.e-3 1e4`.

Answer (score 17):

If you specify the value for your option with an equals sign, `argparse` will not treat it as a separate option, even if it starts with `-`:

```
./blaa.py --xlim='-0.002 1e4'
# As opposed to --xlim '-0.002 1e4'
```

And if the value does not have spaces in it (or other special characters given your shell), you can drop the quotes:

```
./blaa.py --xlim=-0.002
```

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Format.html

With this, there is no need to write your own `type=` parser or redefine the prefix character from `-` to `@` as the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: This doesn't work in this particular case because ---xlim expects two arguments (nargs=2). That is, unless you want to change the convention so that your program _requires_ the invoker to encode the two values as a single string, and your program then does the splitting.

Comment: Ah, good point @itub. If `nargs=2` is the requirement AND any one of the two option values starts with a dash, then there's no getting around it.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code that I use. (It is similar to jeremiahbuddha's but it answers the question more directly since it deals with negative numbers.)

Put this before calling `argparse.ArgumentParser()`

```
for i, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
  if (arg[0] == '-') and arg[1].isdigit(): sys.argv[i] = ' ' + arg
```

Answer (score 9):

Another workaround is to pass in the argument using '`=`' symbol in addition to quoting the argument - i.e., `--xlim="-2.3e14"`

Answer (score 4):

If you are up to modifying `argparse.py` itself, you could change the negative number matcher to handle scientific notation:

In `class _ActionsContainer.__init__()`

```
self._negative_number_matcher = _re.compile(r'^-(\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+)([eE][+\-]?\d+)?$')
```

Or after creating the parser, you could set `parser._negative_number_matcher` to this value.  This approach might have problems if you are creating groups or subparsers, but should work with a simple parser.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by andrewfn's approach, I created a separate helper function to do the `sys.argv` fiddling:

```
def _tweak_neg_scinot():
    import re
    import sys
    p = re.compile('-\\d*\\.?\\d*e', re.I)
    sys.argv = [' ' + a if p.match(a) else a for a in sys.argv]
```

The regex looks for:

- `-` : a negative sign
- `\\d*` : zero or more digits (for oddly formatted values like `-.5e-2` or `-4354.5e-6`)
- `\\.?` : an optional period (e.g., `-2e-5` is reasonable)
- `\\d*` : another set of zero or more digits (for things like `-2e-5` and `-7.e-3`)
- `e` : to match the exponent marker

`re.I` makes it match both `-2e-5` and `-2E-5`. Using `p.match` means that it only searches from the start of each string.