# How to pass a list as a command-line argument after equals sign with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, command-line-interface, argparse

The documented way to pass a list of arguments using argparse uses the following syntax

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--list", nargs="+", default=["a", "b"])
value = parser.parse_args()
```

In the SHELL

`$ python3 example.py --list a b c`

`$ ['a', 'b', 'c']`

The arguments Im working with have leading dashes and require the use of `=` to not be misinterpreted by argparse as another option ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636309/python-argparse-leading-dash-in-argument))

`$ python3 example.py --list=-a`

`$ ['-a']`

I would like to pass in a list of arguments using the `=` syntax. However, Im not sure how to accomplish this. I'm looking for something like the following to work:

`$ python3 example.py --list=-a,-b`

`$ ['-a','-b']`

Comment: You can wrap them in quotes and do the string formatting yourself, otherwise you would need to change the `prefix_chars` to something other than `'-'`

Comment: I think per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025204/python-argparse-issue-with-optional-arguments-which-are-negative-numbers  you could do something like 

`--list " -a"  " -b"`  (note the space right after the open paren)